# -Spark Scala Mongodb- MongoTypeConversionException Cannot cast STRING into a StructType(...)

Tags: mongodb, scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Any help would be very much appreciated.

I am trying to build a dataframe using data from mongodb.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("app")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", uri)
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.collection", "collectionName")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.readPreference.name", "secondary")
      .getOrCreate()

val df = MongoSpark.load(spark).limit(1)
```

and from there i'm trying to read elements row by row, and the schema of the dataframe looks something like this:

```
root
 |-- A: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- B: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- C: string (nullable = true)
 |-- D: string (nullable = true)
 |-- E: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
```

if the dataframe does not include E, dataframe.show() would print out just fine.

However, if the dataframe does inlcude E, then dataframe.show() would give me

```
Cannot cast STRING into a StructType(StructField(a,StringType,true), StructField(b,StringType,true), StructField(c,StringType,true), StructField(d,StringType,true)) (value: BsonString{value='http://...some url...'})
```

I tried pretty much every solution related to this problem listed on stackoverflow, but I'm still having no luck passing this error.

How should I approach this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a example of mongodb document that contains E ? It seems that E is actually an array of string instead of an array of struct of strings.

Comment: @VincentDoba I posted the screenshot of the example of mongodb document below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue occurring becz of data read and data conversion issues with Mongosource type connector.

Me also faced the same situation but you can avoid it by below method :

1. Infer schema =True
2. save the schema in another object
3. again read the data with "saved schema", infer schema= False
4. Load data and you can do whatever analysis with updated one.

Answer (score 0):

E is actually an array of objects that contains multiple strings.

[example of mongodb document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTjty.png)